# Parse date issue with IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I set system datetime format to Swedish (Sweden)
And ran this javascript code in both IE 10 and IE 11, both gave different results. I expect the IE 11 results though.
What and how can be done to correct for IE 10 ?

```
var d = new Date(1444028400000);
var dLocal = d.toLocaleDateString("en-us");
var fixLocalDate  = dLocal.replace(/[^ -~]/g,'');
```

**IE 10 output**
d = Mon Oct 5 00:00:00 PDT 2015
fixLocalDate = den 5 oktober 2015

**IE 11 and Chrome output**
d = Mon Oct 05 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
fixLocalDate = 10‎/‎5‎/‎2015

Comment: Where is the parsing issue? The output from [*toLocaleDateString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) is entirely implementation dependent (even between different versions of the same browser). Where implementations support the ECMA-402 Internationalization API you might get some consistency, but not all do.

Comment: there is a neat library that can help http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks RobG. I get that, but is there a work around for IE 10 implementation to work like IE 11 ?
Philipp, is there no work around with just javascript/jquery ! Agree momentjs is the best for datetime handling, I want to go there after trying all options first with js itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing a locale like this, you are effectively using Intl.DateTimeFormat ojbect - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342822(v=vs.94).aspx

Which is unfortunately not supported in IE10 and below. Usual way of handling this is to use polyfill:

https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/